# Dynamically filtering by a character string using dplyr inside a function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
                folderLoc                         Name
1              ref_hub_v2             dcs_debt_map.txt
2              dcs_hub_v2     dcs_entity_structure.txt
3              ref_hub_v2 shrk_special_exhibit_map.txt
4              ref_hub_v2     etf_legal_struct_map.txt
5              ref_hub_v2      exp_freq_code_map_1.txt
6               ce_events           ce_conferences.txt
7              ref_hub_v2       shrk_cg_source_map.txt
8              ref_hub_v2                  sic_map.txt
9              ref_hub_v2                  fe_item.txt
10 ent_entity_advanced_v1     ent_entity_structure.txt
```

I want to dynamically filter the data based on the input to a function. I have the following function:

```
functionToReadAndSave <- function(data, folderLocation){

  connectionsByFolder <- data %>%
    filter(eval(expression(folderLoc == quote(folderLocation))))
    #filter(folderLoc == quote(folderLocation))

  return(connectionsByFolder)
}

x <- functionToReadAndSave(data = myData, folderLocation == "ref_hub_v2")
```

Where the folder location can change, here I set it to `folderLocation == "ref_hub_v2"` but I will also want to apply the function to `ce_events`, `ent_entity_advanced_v1` etc.

How can I correctly use the `quo`, `eval` etc. to filter the data?

Data:

```
myData <- structure(list(folderLoc = c("ref_hub_v2", "dcs_hub_v2", "ref_hub_v2", 
"ref_hub_v2", "ref_hub_v2", "ce_events", "ref_hub_v2", "ref_hub_v2", 
"ref_hub_v2", "ent_entity_advanced_v1"), Name = c("dcs_debt_map.txt", 
"dcs_entity_structure.txt", "shrk_special_exhibit_map.txt", "etf_legal_struct_map.txt", 
"exp_freq_code_map_1.txt", "ce_conferences.txt", "shrk_cg_source_map.txt", 
"sic_map.txt", "fe_item.txt", "ent_entity_structure.txt")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

I get this error:

```
 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x objeto 'folderLocation' no encontrado
i Input `..1` is `folderLoc == folderLocation`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Traceback:

```
12.
stop(fallback) 
11.
signal_abort(cnd) 
10.
abort(c(cnd_bullet_header(), x = conditionMessage(e), i = cnd_bullet_input_info(), 
    i = cnd_bullet_cur_group_label()), class = "dplyr_error") 
9.
h(simpleError(msg, call)) 
8.
.handleSimpleError(function (e) 
{
    local_call_step(dots = dots, .index = env_filter$current_expression, 
        .fn = "filter") ... 
7.
mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter) 
6.
withCallingHandlers(mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter), error = function(e) {
    local_call_step(dots = dots, .index = env_filter$current_expression, 
        .fn = "filter")
    abort(c(cnd_bullet_header(), x = conditionMessage(e), i = cnd_bullet_input_info(),  ... 
5.
filter_rows(.data, ...) 
4.
filter.data.frame(., folderLoc == folderLocation) 
3.
dplyr::filter(., folderLoc == folderLocation) 
2.
data %>% dplyr::filter(folderLoc == folderLocation) 
1.
functionToReadAndSave(data = myData, folderLocation == "ref_hub_v2")
```

Comment: Wouldn't your input be `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `==` i.e. there is no need to `quote/eval` etc

```
functionToReadAndSave <- function(data, folderLocation){

 data %>%
    filter(folderLoc == folderLocation)
  
}
```

-testing

```
functionToReadAndSave(data = myData, folderLocation = "ref_hub_v2")
folderLoc                         Name
1 ref_hub_v2             dcs_debt_map.txt
2 ref_hub_v2 shrk_special_exhibit_map.txt
3 ref_hub_v2     etf_legal_struct_map.txt
4 ref_hub_v2      exp_freq_code_map_1.txt
5 ref_hub_v2       shrk_cg_source_map.txt
6 ref_hub_v2                  sic_map.txt
7 ref_hub_v2                  fe_item.txt
```

Comment: I was getting an error. You are correct, I was adding two `==` in the function call `folderLocation == "ref_hub_v2"`. It works now.